# Get value from one element to a dynamically generated element

Tags: jquery

I have a page that contains dynamically generated fields that multiply a price by user input, then display a total. My initial function works great, but now i need to have it generate another div that contains the total for each iteration of the total that is generated before.

I need it to generate a field for each of the original with the Total value from the original displayed.

current code:

```js
showHtml = ''
$('.quantity').on('input', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).next('span');
  var cost = parseFloat($(this).prev('.cost').text());
  var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
  $($tr).text('Total: ' + cost * quantity);

});
$('#submit').click(function() {
  $(".total").each(function() {

    showHtml += '<span class="finished" name="finished[]">Total:</span><br/>';

    $('#showme').html(showHtml);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="cost" name="cost[]" value="5">5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]">0</span>
<br/>

<span class="cost" name="cost[]" value="5">5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]">0</span>
<br/>

<span class="cost" name="cost[]" value="5">5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]">0</span>
<br/><br/>

<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
<br/>

<div id="showme">
</div>
```

I am unsure how to pass the value from each one, NOTE: the original fields are generated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this).text()` to get the contents of the current element in the `.each()` loop. Use `.replace()` to remove the `Total:` prefix.

```js
showHtml = ''
$('.quantity').on('input', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).next('span');
  var cost = parseFloat($(this).prev('.cost').text());
  var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
  $($tr).text('Total: ' + cost * quantity);

});
$('#submit').click(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".total").each(function() {
    var thisVal = $(this).text().replace('Total: ', '');
    showHtml += '<span class="finished" name="finished[]">Total:' + thisVal + '</span><br/>';

    $('#showme').html(showHtml);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="cost" name="cost[]" value="5">5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]">0</span>
<br/>

<span class="cost" name="cost[]" value="5">5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]">0</span>
<br/>

<span class="cost" name="cost[]" value="5">5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]">0</span>
<br/><br/>

<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
<br/>

<div id="showme">
</div>
```

Comment: This works! however, I am trying to display the second set of values the same as the top set, not added on to each other.

Comment: Then what's the problem? Just use `$(this).text()` to get the value from the current element in the loop.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've changed the answer to just copy the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would store the value somewhere. Like for example in a variable or on the element itself.

Here is how I did it:
https://jsfiddle.net/fg5ygrke/16/

```
$($tr).data('total', cost * quantity);
```

and

```
showHtml += '<span class="finished" name="finished[]">Total: '+$(this).data('total')+'</span><br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 $("#showme").append()
```

on your button click within

> .each()

do this

```
$(".total").each(function(){
  $('#showme').append('<span class="finished" name="finished[]">'+$(this).text()+'</span><br/>')
  })
```

here is a sample jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/fg5ygrke/17/

Answer (score 0):

Just need to get the .text() from the spans.

```
showHtml = ''
$('.quantity').on('input', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).next('span');
  var cost = parseFloat($(this).prev('.cost').text());
  var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
  $($tr).text('Total: ' + cost * quantity);

});
$('#submit').click(function() {
  $(".total").each(function() {
    curVal = $(this).text(); //add this
    showHtml += '<span class="finished" name="finished[]">Total:' + curVal + '</span><br/>';  //then add it to your showHtml variable

    $('#showme').html(showHtml);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of dynamic adding system which can be achieved in your already existing event handler `$('.quantity').on('input',...);`. Below I have created an example that will explains what needs to be done to achieve this.

```js
showHtml = ''

$('.quantity').on('input', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).next('span');
  var cost = parseFloat($(this).prev('.cost').text());
  var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
  $($tr).text('Total: ' + cost * quantity);
  
  //create a total variable
   var total = 0;
   //loop through elements that contribute to the total
  $('.quantity').each(function(){
    //get a fresh cost and quantity like above
    var cost = parseFloat($(this).prev('.cost').text());
    var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
    //check if the contents are numeric, NaN if nothing is entered (or text)
    if ($.isNumeric(cost * quantity)){
    //add to the total 
      total += (cost * quantity);
    }
  });
 //display the total below
  $('#total').html("Total: " + total);
});

$('#submit').click(function() {
  $(".total").each(function() {

    showHtml += '<span class="finished" name="finished[]">Total:</span><br/>';

    $('#showme').html(showHtml);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="cost" name="cost[]" value="5">5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]">0</span>
<br/>

<span class="cost" name="cost[]" value="5">5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]">0</span>
<br/>

<span class="cost" name="cost[]" value="5">5</span>
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="">
<span class="total" name="total[]">0</span>
<br/><br/>

<div id="total"></div>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
<br/>

<div id="showme">
</div>
```